# How to get Joomla menu item id from menu alias

Tags: php, joomla

I have one article & for that I have created one hidden menu(as per my requirement). I want to get menu item id for that hidden menu.

I have tried  getting the menu item detail by passing the URL to menu getItems function but we need to pass the article id like,

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$menuItem = $menu->getItems( 'link', 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=215', true);
```

but in this case the id=215 which will different on my different server like on local, QA, production etc. But the alias of that menu will be common.
So, can we get the menu item id from menu item alias without writing the SQL query in the code.

Comment: if you need article id Or Menu ID?

Comment: $app = JFactory::getApplication();

Comment: Menu ID --> $Itemid = $app->input->getInt('Itemid');

Comment: Artcle ID - $id = $app->input->getInt('id');